# Mysql index configuration

Tags: sql, mysql, performance

I have a table with 450000 row full of news.
The table schema is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `news` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `readcount` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `cat_id` (`cat_id`),
  KEY `cat_id_2` (`cat_id`,`id`),
  KEY `cat_id_date` (`cat_id`,`date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin5 AUTO_INCREMENT=462679 ;
```

When i run a sql command like below to take some news for a page "x" of the category page it takes more than 15 seconds if x is over 100:

```
select * news where cat_id='4' order by id desc limit 150000,10;
```

explain shows that its using "where" and the index "cat_id_2"

While writing this question i also checked a more simple sql query like this and it also took near to a minute:

```
select * from haberler order by id desc limit 40000,10;
```

if the sql is like the following one it takes just a few milliseconds:

```
select * from haberler order by id desc limit 20,10;
```

My my.cnf configuration is like this:

```
skip-locking
skip-innodb
query_cache_limit=1M
query_cache_size=256M
query_cache_type=1
max_connections=30
interactive_timeout=600000
#wait_timeout=5
#connect_timeout=5
thread_cache_size=384
key_buffer=256M
join_buffer=4M
max_allowed_packet=16M
table_cache=1024
record_buffer=1M
sort_buffer_size=64M
read_buffer_size=16M
max_connect_errors=10
# Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency
thread_concurrency=2
myisam_sort_buffer_size=128M
long_query_time         = 1
log_slow_queries        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
max_heap_table_size=512M
```

The website is running on a core2duo with 2GB of RAM.
I think that the problem may be caused by the sort_buffer_size but i'm not sure.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Could also be your indexes, have you look into this aspect?

Comment: There's a number of inconsistencies in your question, please could you edit it to make it more clear?

Comment: it must be fixed now, the names used in the table were turkish originally, seems like i forgot to translate some of them to english.
sorry for my bad english by the way.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Update:**

See this article in my blog for the more detailed analysis of the problem:

- [**MySQL ORDER BY / LIMIT performance: late row lookups**](http://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/)

---

When you issue something like `LIMIT 150000, 10`, it means that `MySQL` should traverse these `150,000` records and find the next `10`.

Traversing the index is slow in `MySQL`.

Also, `MySQL` is not capable of doing late row lookups.

Theoretically, if you do `ORDER BY id LIMIT 100000, 10`, it is enough to use the index to find the values from `100000` to `100010`, then look up only `10` rows that satisfy that index and return them.

All major systems except `MySQL` are aware of it and look the rows up only if the values are really to be returned.

`MySQL`, however, looks up every row.

Try to rewrite your query as this:

```
SELECT  news.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    news
        WHERE   cat_id='4'
        ORDER BY
                id DESC
        LIMIT 150000, 10
        ) o
JOIN    news
ON      news.id = o.id
```

Comment: your query seems to be working much more faster, but i cant understand the reason.
can you please tell the reason also?

Comment: Late row lookup, I described this in my post. My query selects only `10` records from the table itself, your original query selects all `150,000` records and discards them. I'll make a blog post on this this evening, in which I'll cover it in more detail.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Please do - haven't really considered the `*` part of `SELECT *` to be the culprit here.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Mucho gracias for the extended explanation - http://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/

Comment: Nice article. I must say that I find MySQL's behaviour appalling. It was already bordering on ridiculous when we had to manually force index usage, but rewriting the whole query? Using an inner join on the very same table?! Only so we have a manually optimized query to guide the original one?!?