# MySQL: simple schema, joining in a view and sorting on unrelated attribute causes unbearable performance hit

Tags: mysql, database, performance, view

I'm creating a database model for use by a diverse amount of applications and different kinds of database servers (though I'm mostly testing on MySQL and SQLite now). It's a really simple model that basically consists of one central **matches** table and many **attribute** tables that have the match_id as their primary key and one other field (the attribute value itself). Said in other words, every match has exactly one of every type of attribute and every attribute is stored in a seperate table. After experiencing some rather bad performance whilst sorting and filtering on these attributes (`FROM matches LEFT JOIN attributes_i_want on primary index`) I decided to try to improve it. To this end I added an index on every attribute value column. Sorting and filtering performance increased a lot for easy queries.

This simple schema is basically a requirement for the application, so it is able to auto-discover and use attributes. Thus, to create more complex attributes that are actually based on other results, I decided to use VIEWs that turn one or more other tables that don't necessarily match up to the attribute-like schema into an attribute-schema. I call these meta-attributes (they aren't directly editable either). However, to the application this is all transparant, and so it happily joins in the VIEW as well when it wants to. The problem: **it kills performance**. When the VIEW is joined in without sorting on any attribute, performance is still acceptable, but combining a retrieval of the VIEW with sorting is unacceptably slow (on the order of 1s). Even after reading quite a bit of tutorials on indexing and some questions here on stack overflow, I can't seem to help it.

_Prerequisites for a solution: in one way or another, num_duplicates must exist as a table or view with the columns match_id and num_duplicates to look like an attribute. I can't change the way attributes are discovered and used. So if I want to see num_duplicates appear in the application it'll have to be as some kind of view or materialized table that makes a num_duplicates table._

#### Relevant parts of the schema

Main table:

```
CREATE TABLE `matches` (
  `match_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `source_name` text,
  `target_name` text,
  `transformation` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`match_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Example of a normal attribute (indexed):

```
CREATE TABLE `error` (
  `match_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `error` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`match_id`),
  KEY `error_index` (`error`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

(all normal attributes, like `error`, are basically the same)

Meta-attribute / VIEW:

```
CREATE VIEW num_duplicates 
AS SELECT duplicate AS match_id, COUNT(duplicate) AS num_duplicates 
    FROM duplicate 
    GROUP BY duplicate
```

(this is the only meta-attribute I'm using right now)

#### Simple query with indexing on the attribute value columns (the part improved by indexes)

```
SELECT matches.match_id, source_name, target_name, transformation FROM matches
    INNER JOIN error ON matches.match_id = error.match_id
ORDER BY error.error
```

(the performance on this query increased a lot because of the index on error)
(the runtime of this query is on the order of 0.0001 sec)

#### Slightly more complex queries and their runtimes including the meta-attribute (the still bad part)

```
SELECT 
    matches.match_id, source_name, target_name, transformation, STATUS , volume, error, COMMENT , num_duplicates
FROM matches
    INNER JOIN STATUS ON matches.match_id = status.match_id
    INNER JOIN error ON matches.match_id = error.match_id
    LEFT JOIN num_duplicates ON matches.match_id = num_duplicates.match_id
    INNER JOIN volume ON matches.match_id = volume.match_id
    INNER JOIN COMMENT ON matches.match_id = comment.match_id
```

(runtime: 0.0263sec) <--- still acceptable

```
SELECT matches.match_id, source_name, target_name, transformation, STATUS , volume, error, COMMENT , num_duplicates
FROM matches
    INNER JOIN STATUS ON matches.match_id = status.match_id
    INNER JOIN error ON matches.match_id = error.match_id
    LEFT JOIN num_duplicates ON matches.match_id = num_duplicates.match_id
    INNER JOIN volume ON matches.match_id = volume.match_id
    INNER JOIN COMMENT ON matches.match_id = comment.match_id
ORDER BY error.error
LIMIT 20, 20
```

(runtime: 0.8866 sec) <--- not acceptable (the query speed is exactly the same with the LIMIT as without the LIMIT, **note**: if I could get the version with the LIMIT to be fast that would already be a big win. I presume it has to scan the entire table and so the limit doesn't matter too much)

#### EXPLAIN of the last query

Of course I tried to solve it myself before coming here, but I must admit I'm not that good at these things and haven't found a way to remove the offending performance killer yet. I know it's most likely the using filesort but I don't know how to get rid of it.

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY error   index   PRIMARY,match_id    error_index 9   NULL    53909   Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY COMMENT eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   tangbig4.error.match_id 1    
1   PRIMARY STATUS  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   tangbig4.COMMENT.match_id   1   Using where
1   PRIMARY matches eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   tangbig4.COMMENT.match_id   1   Using where
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2    
1   PRIMARY volume  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   tangbig4.matches.match_id   1   Using where
2   DERIVED duplicate   index   NULL    duplicate_index 5   NULL    49222   Using index
```

By the way, the query without the sort, which still runs acceptably, is EXPLAIN'ed like this:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY COMMENT ALL PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    49610    
1   PRIMARY error   eq_ref  PRIMARY,match_id    PRIMARY 4       tangbig4.COMMENT.match_id   1    
1   PRIMARY matches eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   tangbig4.COMMENT.match_id   1    
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2    
1   PRIMARY STATUS  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   tangbig4.COMMENT.match_id   1    
1   PRIMARY volume  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   tangbig4.matches.match_id   1       Using where
2   DERIVED duplicate   index   NULL    duplicate_index 5   NULL    49222   Using index
```

#### Question

So, my question is if someone who know more about databases/MySQL is able to find me a way that I can use/research to increase the performance of my last query.

I've been thinking quite a lot about materialized views but they are not natively supported in MySQL and since I'm going for as wide a range of SQL servers as possible this might not be idea. I'm hoping maybe a change to the queries or views might help or possible an extra index.

**EDIT**: Some random thoughts I've been having about the query:

- VERY FAST: joining all tables, excluding the VIEW, **sorting**
- ACCEPTABLE: joining all tables, including the VIEW, **no sorting**
- DOG SLOW: joining all tables, including the VIEW, **sorting**

But: **the VIEW has no influence at all on the sorting, none of it's attributes or even the attributes in its constituent tables are used to sort. Why does includingg the sort impact performance that much then? Is there any way I can convince the database to sort first and then just join up the VIEW? Or can I convince it that the VIEW is not important for sorting?**

**EDIT2**: Following the suggestion by @ace for creating a VIEW and then joining at first didn't seem to help:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `matches_joined`;
CREATE VIEW `matches_joined` AS (
  SELECT matches.match_id, source_name, target_name, transformation, STATUS , volume, error, COMMENT
  FROM matches
  INNER JOIN STATUS ON matches.match_id = status.match_id
  INNER JOIN error ON matches.match_id = error.match_id
  INNER JOIN volume ON matches.match_id = volume.match_id
  INNER JOIN COMMENT ON matches.match_id = comment.match_id
  ORDER BY error.error
);
```

followed by:

```
SELECT matches_joined.*, num_duplicates
FROM matches_joined
LEFT JOIN num_duplicates ON matches_joined.match_id = num_duplicates.match_id
```

However, using LIMIT on the view did make a difference:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `matches_joined`;
CREATE VIEW `matches_joined` AS (
  SELECT matches.match_id, source_name, target_name, transformation, STATUS , volume, error, COMMENT
  FROM matches
  INNER JOIN STATUS ON matches.match_id = status.match_id
  INNER JOIN error ON matches.match_id = error.match_id
  INNER JOIN volume ON matches.match_id = volume.match_id
  INNER JOIN COMMENT ON matches.match_id = comment.match_id
  ORDER BY error.error
  LIMIT 0, 20
);
```

Afterwards, the query ran at an acceptable speed. This is already a nice result. However, I feel that I'm jumping through hoops to force the database to do what I want and the reduction in time is probably only caused by the fact that it now only has to sort 20 rows. What if I have more rows? Is there any other way to force the database to see that joining in the `num_duplicates` VIEW doesn't influence the sorting in the least? Could I perhaps change the query that makes the VIEW a bit?

Comment: As I was reading your post I had the same idea you put up in your EDIT's first bullet point. The view is slowing you down and all the rest is OK. I wonder if you can use this method and only join to the view at the end. Make the query without the view into an in-line nested query (maybe even include DISTINCT to force it to execute separately) and join the view as the last step. If you could limit the number of rows in the inner query with a row number condition that would be even less rows to join at the end and maybe no need for distinct.

Comment: You're right, trying to get the VIEW joined up later is my primary train of thought at this point. I'm trying to see what a good way to do this (preferably across at least MySQL and SQLite) would be. I don't really get how DISTINCT would help me exactly here, but that's probably because when it comes to databases I'm really inexperienced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things that can be tested if you haven't tried them yet.
Create a view for all joins with sorting.

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `matches_joined`;
CREATE VIEW `matches_joined` AS (
  SELECT matches.match_id, source_name, target_name, transformation, STATUS , volume, error, COMMENT
  FROM matches
  INNER JOIN STATUS ON matches.match_id = status.match_id
  INNER JOIN error ON matches.match_id = error.match_id
  INNER JOIN volume ON matches.match_id = volume.match_id
  INNER JOIN COMMENT ON matches.match_id = comment.match_id
  ORDER BY error.error
);
```

Then join them with `num_duplicates`

```
SELECT matches_joined.*, num_duplicates
FROM matches_joined
LEFT JOIN num_duplicates ON matches_joined.match_id = num_duplicates.match_id
```

I'm assuming that as pointed out in [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html), this query will utilize the `order by` clause in the view matches_joined.

Some information that may help on optimization.
[MySQL ::   MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual :: 7.3.1.11 ORDER BY Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

Comment: As I explained in the question, and as you can see in the schema that I posted, there is already an index on error. Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: error.error_index is not a column, it's the name of the index itself

(in other words: error_index is an index on error.error)

Comment: Let me check on that more, filesort is the default algorithm for sorting. It's mentioned by the way that adding an 'order by to a view' is applicable when the query joining with it does not use it's own order by.

Comment: I'm not sure if this scenario A, **joining all tables, including the VIEW(has own sorting), no sorting** is acceptable or faster than **joining all tables, including the VIEW(has no own sorting), sorting**

Comment: What are you implying? That the tests I do her on my computer are flukes? The view itself doesn't have an ORDER BY clause, in both cases. So you're right that it doesn't appear to have an own sorting. I have read somewhere that MySQL (or was that SQLite?) will also perform sorting on the GROUP BY columns, in which case the VIEW would be sorted on the "num_duplicate" column or something. If you are implying that I should sort my view first, I could try that. On what should I sort?

Comment: I'm not implying your tests are fluke. :)
By the way, how fast is `SELECT 
    matches.match_id, source_name, target_name, transformation, STATUS , volume, error, COMMENT , num_duplicates
FROM matches
    INNER JOIN STATUS ON matches.match_id = status.match_id
    INNER JOIN error ON matches.match_id = error.match_id
    INNER JOIN volume ON matches.match_id = volume.match_id
    INNER JOIN COMMENT ON matches.match_id = comment.match_id`. Sorry for the formatting, basically all tables without the view `num_duplicates`

Comment: That's very fast. If I don't include the view everything is fast, with or without sorting. If I DO include the view, everything becomes dog-slow when I start sorting. (note that as I said in the question, the sort order isn't dependent of the view, so I think it's strange that it would be slower)

Comment: Ah, how about trying inner join for comparison. I'm curious how inner join and left join impacts performance.

Comment: That doesn't work, it has to be a left join because the **num_duplicates** view in general will only contain rows for those matches that actually have duplicates. If I used an INNER JOIN I would only get results for the matches with at least 1 duplicate, which is not what I want. However, the fact that an INNER JOIN without sorting provides at least acceptable performance probably means that the INNER JOIN is not impacting too much. As you can see in my question: performance with sorting is 40x worse than performance without, irrespective of INNER JOIN

Comment: I see you edited your answer, so I'm going to respond to that :). A problem is that my query is actually a class of queries. They all look like the one I'm trying to optimize but they're not the same. I guess I can try recreating the VIEW on every new query, joining in meta-attributes later, if the performance truly is better. Though I suspect that the same argument for 'ORDER BY' being used/ignored by the view is also valid for my original queries. I'll try it when I get the time! Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer with the tests I did. If I can find no cleaner way to do it in a few days I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thanks for all the effort!

Comment: I'll also think of some way to optimize it further. I've been looking at some of my old databases but the records are not that many. One of the solutions I thought of is to archive records that are not needed in the daily transactions but I'm not sure if it's applicable in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was more or less solved by the "VIEW" suggestion that @ace made, but several other types of queries still had performance issues (notably large OFFSET's). In the end a large improvement on all queries of this form was had by simply forcing [late-row lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612957/mysql-index-configuration). Note that it is commonly claimed that this is only necessary for MySQL because MySQL always performs early-row lookup and that other databases like PostgreSQL don't suffer from this problem. However, extensive benchmarks of my application have pointed out that PostgreSQL benefits greatly from this approach as well.